# persistence.xml configuration to fetch a property value from property file dynamically

Tags: hibernate, persistence.xml

I have persistence.xml in my project.
In this I have use different property tags for Data Base User Name and Password for same.
I want value of this property to be set at run time while loading.

Instead of having such code,

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mysql" />   
</properties>
```

I want to have code similar to this

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=${DB_USERNAME} />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=${DB_PASSWORD} />    
</properties>
```

But I don't want to use Spring configuration.

Is there any way?